# How to get all Users and its orders as a sub-set in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I Have a table like

```
user.id
user.firstname
user.lastname
```

another table I have is

```
order.id
order.userid
order.name
order.price
```

with this query:

```
SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, order.name
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders ON user.id = order.userid;
```

If I have 3 users and each user have 3 order, I get 9 rows in results.
how can I get the 3 rows having subsets of 3 order objects in them.

Here is an example of output I need

firstname | lastname | onderNames

---

im        | ah      | book, pen, watch

---

abc.      | dff.    | rice, wheat

thanks in advance

Comment: SQL has no sense of 'arrays'...

Comment: yes sql has no sense of array. but the data it return an array. and there must be way to add multiple orders under the single column as results

Comment: I have edited my question now I have called it as subset

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(fieldyouwant SEPARATOR ',')` and `GROUP_BY user.id`.

Comment: Please show what you expect as the result.

Comment: @BenM I have added an example of output required. thanks

Comment: @HoldOffHunger you are right. please post as answer I will mark it as correct so it help others as well. thanks

Comment: No worries, just mark Gordon Linoff's answer as correct, it seems right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an aggregation query.  The most common structure is:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(o.name SEPARTOR ', ') as names
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.id = o.userid
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

This puts the result in a string.  You can also put the result in JSON -- which is also a string but formatted as a JSON array -- using `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.